# AWS S3 bucket storage type and sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I'm using CLI to sync assets over from one bucket to another (back up in different region) . The main bucket has Intelligent Tiering and the back up has Standard-IA.

When I run a sync between the 2 buckets, the assets appearing in the backup bucket are appearing as standard storage class rather than standard-IA.

Why's this?
Altered CLI command:
`aws --profile aws-bb-this s3 sync s3://bb-this-tractor-prod/tractor-download-1/ s3://bb-this-tractor-prod-us-east-1/tractor-download-1/`

Comment: I think you need `--storage-class` parameter.

Comment: Adding: ```--storage-class STANDARD_IA``` should solve this then, didn't realise CLI would default to standard.

Comment: There are no default storage class for bucket. You can have lifesycle polices which will transition object from standard to standard_ai for instance. But if you don't specify storage class for an object when you upload it, it will be standard until lifecycle rules kick in.